# Visual Fox Pro 6.0 Query of Logical DataType not working!

Tags: sql, foxpro, visual-foxpro

My current system has a query to generate a tax report. The problem is that sometimes orders go into our system that never get submitted but are still counted in the tax report. The flag that sets an order as submitted is called 'complete' and it will be set to TRUE using the logical datatype.

Two issues arise from the following code. First, it seems as though the field I am using as a constraint 'complete' is a FoxPro reserved function because it lights up in blue while in FoxPro. The second problem is that it will not exclude those records that never get submitted (basically the constraint is not working).

EDITED CODE:

```
sele bkmast
set order to county
set filt to between(sysdate, m.ld_start, m.ld_end)
go top
m.lh_countylines = ''
select 000000.0000 as ordamt, import, county, 00000000.00 as amount, date() as start, date() as end dist;
    from bkmast ;
    where !empty(county) ;
    .and. alltrim(county) !='0' ;
    .and. alltrim(county) !='8.00_Wyoming' ;
    .and. alltrim(county) !='Select County' ;
    order by county ;
    into table countytax
m.ln_total=0
m.ln_countamt = 0
scan
    m.lc_county = alltrim(county)
    sele bkmast
    seek m.lc_county
    sum tax to m.ln_amt while county=m.lc_county
    seek m.lc_county            
    sum ordamt to m.ln_ordamt while county=m.lc_county 
    sele countytax
    replace ordamt with m.ln_ordamt
    replace amount with m.ln_amt
    replace startDate with m.ld_start
    replace endDate with m.ld_end
    m.ln_countamt = m.ln_countamt + ordamt
    m.ln_total = m.ln_total + amount
    m.lh_countylines = m.lh_countylines+elemerge(html_frm("TAXCOUNTY1"))
endscan
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if a trick with using a name expression could help, i.e. `("complete")` instead of `complete`. The Fox Pro version I used last was 2.6 for DOS, so not sure if it can work now.

Comment: @Andriy M - I tried that and no luck either. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having worked with Foxpro since FoxBase back in '87, I've never known a "complete" command, nor is it directly documented in the VFP Help (yet as stated, DOES highlight in blue as a function call via Complete()  ).  Additionally the .AND. is long ago old indicator of query.  The "End" though IS a keyword.  I would try by qualifying the columns by adding the alias to the query and changing End to EndDate (and pairing up Start to StartDate), such as...

From the result of your other comment, I would do your pre-querying directly in the select statement, then do your updates...

```
SELECT 
      bk.Import,;
      bk.county,;
      sum( bk.OrdAmt ) AS OrdAmt,;
      sum( bk.Tax ) AS Amount,;
      m.ld_Start AS startDate,;
      m.ld_End AS endDate;
   FROM ;
      bkmast bk ;
   where ;
         sysdate between m.ld_start and m.ld_End;
     AND NOT empty( ALLTRIM( bk.county )) ;
     AND NOT alltrim( bk.county ) == '0' ;
     and NOT alltrim( bk.county ) == '8.00_Wyoming' ;
     and NOT alltrim( bk.county ) == 'Select County' ;
     AND bk.complete;
   group by ;
      bk.Import,;
      bk.county;
   order by;
      bk.county ;
   into;
      table countytax
```

In this case, since the aggregations of order amount and tax, you don't need to go back to the BKMast table... its already done... you can just cycle through the result set directly.  The only thing left would be to sum up the total tax and order amounts... If those variables are not used within your   elemerge(html_frm("TAXCOUNTY1"))   call, you can just pre-sum those directly

```
select CountyTax
sum OrdAmt, Amount to m.ln_CountAmt, m.ln_Total

scan
    */ These two already summed up from before the scan loop
    ** m.ln_countamt = m.ln_countamt + ordamt
    ** m.ln_total = m.ln_total + amount

    */ Now, continue with the eleMerge() function which will already have the
    */ values in the CountyTax table already summed up
    m.lc_county = alltrim(county)
    m.lh_countylines = m.lh_countylines+elemerge(html_frm("TAXCOUNTY1"))
endscan
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I truly appreciate it. I tried this code and received a syntax error at the FROM command.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not supply the entire query I guess. Look at my original post and I will put the whole query in that post.

Comment: @bOkeifus, updated with the rest of your query... also, uses context of your "set filter" so that isn't specifically needed any more.

Comment: I fixed the 'FROM' error. I had to put the next line right next to the 'FROM' statement. But now that the 'FROM' syntax error is not a problem, I am having an issue with the 'seek' command afterwards. Check my original post for the seek command. It states ' Table has no index order set.'

Comment: @bOkeifus, I've just finished revising and testing... try the NEW post.  the from/where were missing semi-colons...

Comment: @DRapp - Thanks for all of the help. That did fix the FROM issue but now I am seeing that my 'Table has no index order set.' When I attempt to seek afterward. I updated the code in my initial post.

Comment: @bOkeifus, revised and simplified your scan loop to... You shouldn't need to keep re-seeking and adding up totals.. They can be done in the SQL-select

Comment: @DRapp, thank you for all of your help so far. That last query worked, but I still need to show all of the counties regardless of whether they actually product tax values or not. Anything to fix that.

Comment: @bOkeifus, what is the table name that has the master list of ALL counties

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I found out that this is not important. I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you run a query where the only this in the WHERE clause is complete:

```
SELECT ;
  000000.0000 OrdAmt,;
  bk.Import,;
  bk.county,;
  00000000.00 Amount,;
  date() as startDate,;
  date() as endDate;
from bkmast bk;
where bk.Complete ;
into cursor csrTest
```

Does that get the right set of records? What I'm getting at is that maybe the Complete field doesn't contain what you think it does.

Tamar